# homebrew locate installed files path

Tags: ruby, bash, macos, installation, homebrew

I have a [homebrew](https://brew.sh/) package that I was able to push through [GitHub](https://github.com/): [diagnosticator](https://github.com/cccnrc/homebrew-diagnosticator)

This is a simple [ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org) file ([diagnosticator.rb](https://github.com/cccnrc/homebrew-diagnosticator/blob/main/diagnosticator.rb)) that points to the actual hosting repository: [diagnosticator-mac](https://github.com/cccnrc/diagnosticator-mac) and provides instructions on how to install files:

```rb
class Diagnosticator < Formula
  desc "Diagnosticator Mac OS homebrew package"
  homepage "https://diagnosticator.com"
  url "https://github.com/cccnrc/diagnosticator-mac/archive/refs/tags/v0.1.11.tar.gz"
  sha256 "f36987ce96c7be269da12b9dce8186c5245aef4046fe62173a145024b5e88b98"
  license "MIT"

  depends_on "docker"
  depends_on "docker-compose"
  depends_on "wget"
  depends_on "jq"

  def install
    bin.install "diagnosticator"
    bin.install "diagnosticator-mac.sh"
    bin.install Dir["files"]
    prefix.install "README.md"
  end
end
```

From the [diagnosticator executable](https://github.com/cccnrc/diagnosticator-mac/blob/main/diagnosticator) I have to refer to [diagnosticator-mac.sh executable](https://github.com/cccnrc/diagnosticator-mac/blob/main/diagnosticator-mac.sh), I am now referring it as:

```sh
MAC_EXE=/usr/local/bin/diagnosticator-mac.sh
```

but I guess I can simply change it to:

```sh
MAC_EXE=diagnosticator-mac.sh
```

as it will be found on the `$PATH` after installation.

From [diagnosticator-mac.sh](https://github.com/cccnrc/diagnosticator-mac/blob/main/diagnosticator-mac.sh) I have to refer to files in the [files](https://github.com/cccnrc/diagnosticator-mac/tree/main/files) folder that are installed through `bin.install Dir["files"]`, I have now:

```sh
DIAGNOSTICATOR_FILES_DIR=/usr/local/opt/diagnosticator/bin/files
```

but I noticed that in a couple of different Mac machines they ended up in different locations based on how users installed [homebrew](https://brew.sh/).

How can I find a way to point the [diagnosticator-mac.sh](https://github.com/cccnrc/diagnosticator-mac/blob/main/diagnosticator-mac.sh) executable to that [files](https://github.com/cccnrc/diagnosticator-mac/tree/main/files) folder however [homebrew](https://brew.sh/) was installed?

---

If you want to try it:

```sh
brew install cccnrc/diagnosticator/diagnosticator
```

Answer (score 0):

Homebrew determines the path for you, and stores it in the variable [`HOMEBREW_PREFIX`](https://docs.brew.sh/Formula-Cookbook#variables-for-directory-locations)

You could use [inreplace](https://docs.brew.sh/Formula-Cookbook#inreplace) to swap your hardcoded prefix with the homebrew prefix.

```rb
# Iterate through the files, replacing the prefix
%w[diagnosticator diagnosticator-mac.sh].each do |file|
  inreplace file, "/usr/local", HOMEBREW_PREFIX
end
```

Comment: Thank you so much Haren, can I just put this on `diagnosticato-mac.sh` bash executable? And from there how do I refer to files? As example, `DOCKER_COMPOSE_FILE=${DIAGNOSTICATOR_FILES_DIR}/docker-compose.yml` would it be simply `DOCKER_COMPOSE_FILE=docker-compose.yml`?

Comment: You shouldn't need to do anything in the shell file, this code is for the homebrew ruby formula. It replaces all instances of `/usr/local` with the correct prefix. It will therefore replace `/usr/local` in `DIAGNOSTICATOR_FILES_DIR`. Let me know if I've misunderstood anything and I'd be happy to help :)

Comment: ok so I just add it in the ruby script (which part exactly?) and everything should work fine?

Comment: Add it to the beginning of your install function, and hopefully, everything should be good